# How to enable autocomplete for SpriteKit in XCode 5.1.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, documentation

I am playing around with SpriteKit framework in XCode 5.1.1 and there doesn't seem to be any autocomplete for properties. (zRotation, position etc..)

I checked for new documentation and there doesn't seem to be any new documents.

I find it difficult to learn when autocomplete isn't working. It works for other frameworks and general autocompletes (CGRectMake etc..)

Check out the below image. I am trying to autocomplete to the 'position' property, but it doesn't show up.

[image]

And again here trying to type out the "zRotation":

[image]

Any thoughts on what I may have to rebuild or reload?

Comment: As written it's borderline ontopic because it's about how to use Xcode and not about about software development per se. Let's see whether somebody has a an answer for you. If not we can help you in moving the question to another site on the SE network where more developers hang out.